# Restful web services unit testing/mocking in java 1.5 version

Tags: java, unit-testing, rest, mocking, mockito

I have java code hosted in java 1.5 environment which acts like a client calling another third party restful webservices. Now I want to write unit test case in my application to mock the behavior the third party restful web services. Any thoughts on how to do this ?

From the internet, I could see lot of tools available to do that but they require java > 1.6 . For example: rest-assured, restito etc...

I have a strict limitation of using java 1.5 as the main classes have dependency on 1.5 version.

My compile/runtime versions are 1.5 only

Please share your thoughts

Answer (score 0):

You could write a stub service, that the client can call too.
Depending on how much interaction the client/test code needs with the stub would define your interface for the stub, but at its simplest it would just return canned response for a given set of inputs.

If you have control over where the stub is running and what runtime it is running with you 
don't need to restrict yourself to java 1.5

Is there any reason you can't run tests in a modern environment, for general functionality before deployment to the Java 1.5 host?

I would suggest your stub doesn't have to run in a 1.5 environment, just your client and its tests.

Comment: This project is built using maven with src/target as jdk 1.5. The jars built using this project is imported via ivy into another ANT based (biggger) project which is restricted to jvm 1.5. Basically I guess you are asking me to write the stub for the third party restful service and deploy it to some kind of j2ee container which is jdk > 1.5  - is that right ? Any recommendations for your approach ?

Comment: If you can point the client at SoapUI you should be able to use that as a stub, thats is a more manual route though.

You could use something like Spark (Java Server) or Jetty, to host a stub.
It really depends on what kind of testing you are doing.

Does seem strange being limited to 1.5 given 1.6 is pretty much out of support these days.